# How do I render the depth map using Unity URP?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, urp, shader-graph

I want to recreate the "Moebius" style in Unity. I have found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jlKNOirh66E) where someone achieves it, but he only shares the concept and the result and not the source code.

Here are some snippets from that video:

*Original scene*:
[image: Original scene]

*Depth map*:
[image: Depth map]

*Sobel filter*:
[image: Sobel filter]

*"Moebius" style*:
[image: "Moebius" style]

Since the first step is to detect the edges in the scene and draw those I have looked around and found a couple of other videos focusing on outlines:

- [Creating an Outline Effect as a Post-Process in Unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehyMwVnnnTg)
- [Toon Outlines in Unity URP, Shader Graph Using Sobel Edge Detection! ✔️ 2020.3 | Game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMt6DcaMxcE)
- [Dev Tutorial AMAZING Free OUTLINE for URP (Screen Space Outline Unity)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VpIIFdwTKyQ)
- [Outlines - Devlog 2 | A Cozy Creature Collecting and Management Game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMqio9NsqmM)
- [Unlocking The Power Of Unity's Scriptable Render Pipeline](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9fa4uFm1eCE)

Among those videos there are also two Github repositories referenced:

- [Robinseibold / Unity-URP-Outlines](https://github.com/Robinseibold/Unity-URP-Outlines)
- [NedMakesGames / RendererFeatureBlitMat](https://github.com/NedMakesGames/RendererFeatureBlitMat)

I've noticed that all those are fairly out of date. So I don't know if it's because of that or because I am new to scripting render pipelines, but I couldn't get it to work.

To understand the basics it would be great to know how to render the depth map of the scene, more specifically the *DepthNormals*, like shown in the first video. Ideally by using a shader, so I can work with a shader graph to achieve the rest, but I don't know how to apply a shader to the whole scene / camera.

I should mention that I am using Unity 2022.2.19.